# C++ Add method logic

Tags: c++, linked-list, containers

I've been trying to figure out where I've gone wrong. My add method doesn't detect if same student is added twice. P.s list is pointing to the head of the container.

```
int add(Student* s)
{
    Container *follow = list;

    Container *newNode = new Container;
    newNode->student = s;


    if (list == NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        list = newNode;
        //cout << "Student Added!";
        return 1;

    }
    else if (s->getFirstName().compare(list->student->getFirstName()) == 0) //duplication check
    {
        if (s->getLastName().compare(list->student->getLastName()) == 0) //Same Student
        {
            free(newNode->student); //Memory Mangment
            free(newNode);
            //  cout << "Student Exist!";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else    //adding at the beginning of the list
    {
        newNode->next = list;
        list = newNode;
        //  cout << "Student Added!";
        return 1;
    }

    Container* temp = list->next;

    while (temp != NULL) // inserting inbetween 2 nodes in the list
    {
        if (s->getFirstName().compare(list->student->getFirstName()) == 0)
        {
            if (s->getLastName().compare(list->student->getLastName()) == 0) //Same Student
            {
                free(newNode->student); //Memory Mangment
                free(newNode);
                //  cout << "Student Exist!";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->next = list;
            list = newNode;
            //  cout << "Student Added!";
            return 1;
        }
        follow = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    follow->next = newNode; // inserting at the end of the list
    return 1;


}
```

I modified the code to the following but i'm still getting a run time error.

```
 Container* follow = list;
 Container* newNode = (Container*) malloc(sizeof(Container));
 newNode->student = s;
 newNode->next = NULL;

if (list == NULL) // inserting into an empty list
{
    list = newNode; 
    return 1;
}

while (list != NULL)
{
    if (search(s) == NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = list;
        list = newNode;
        return 1;
    }
    else if (search(s) != NULL)
    {
        free(newNode->student); //Memory Mangment
        free(newNode);
        //  cout << "Student Exist!";
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Below is the implementation of search
// This function is already implemented for you. If the requested student does not exist on the list, NULL is returned.

```
   Student* search(Student* s)
  {
  Container *traverser = list;

 while (traverser != NULL)
 {
    if (traverser->student->getFirstName() == s->getFirstName() && traverser->student->getLastName() == s->getLastName())
        return traverser->student;
    traverser = traverser->next;
}
return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: Re ` _CONTAINER_H_` please note, identifiers starting with underscore followed by uppercase, are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Instead of `compare` invocations, for `std::string` you can just use `==`.

Comment: After C++11, instead of `NULL` the general preference is for using `nullptr`: that's what it's for, why it was introduced even though we already had `NULL`.

Comment: Tip: You can use programmers' editors or a freestanding free tool like Astyle to **format your code** before posting it here.

Comment: Instead of `int`, `0` and `1` to represent booleans, you can use `bool`, `false` and `true`.

Comment: Something allocated with `new` must be deallocated with `delete`, not via the C library's `free`. Assuming that the call to `free` is invoking the C library's function, that's **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: The `get` prefix is a Java-ism. It serves no useful purpose in C++. On the contrary, it adds verbosity that makes it harder to read and write code.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop logic says, among other things, that if the new student's first name is different than the first name in the existing first node, then just insert it.

Comment: I combined the 2 if statements together

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is doing the following:
- if first name of student is different than first element of the loop --> add student
- else if first name is the same and last name is the same --> exit
- else if first name is the same and last name is different --> go to next element.

This means that on the first element of the list that has a different name than the one of the student you want to add, the student will be added, regardless of the content of the list.

Example: 
current list : [Ben benson, jack jackson, john johnson]
You plan to add jack jackson.
The first check will find that "ben" is not equal to "jack" and proceed to add "jack jackson".

Solution:
- Check the elements of the list one by one until your student is found or you reach the end of the list. (this will be your while loop.)
- After your while loop, if the student was not found, add the student.